# Does a zero duality gap imply global optimality?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, duality-theorems

Let's say we are given a nonlinear optimization primal problem (P).

Suppose that the dual problem (D) to the primal optimization problem (P) achieves a zero duality gap with a solution to the primal problem.

Does a zero duality gap imply that the dual solution achieves the same value as the globally optimal primal solution? Or can we have a zero duality gap with a locally optimal primal solution?

Comment: If $F_\text{primal}(x_0)=F_\text{dual}(y_0)$ for some primal feasible $x_0$ and dual feasible $y_0$ then $x_0$ and $y_0$ are *global* optimal solutions to (P) and (D) respectively.